# Processar argumentos de uma linha de comando

Tags: python

Olá, estou tentando trabalhar com processo de argumentos da linha de comando, vou mostrar um exemplo de linha de comando que estou utilizando:

```
user@notebook$ python arquivo.py -nome Lucas --idade 12 --pais Brasil
```

Código:

```py
import sys
import argparse


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Descricao')
    parser.add_argument('-nome', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--idade', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--pais', required=True)
    
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print("Nome = {}".format(args.nome))
    print("Idade = {}".format(args.idade))
    print("País = {}".format(args.pais))

    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Saída:

```
Nome = Lucas
Idade = 12
País = Brasil
```

Gostaria de saber se há a possibilidade de receber, por exemplo a **idade** sem precisar utilizar o **--idade** na linha de comando, dessa forma:

```
user@notebook$ python arquivo.py -nome Lucas 12 --pais Brasil
```

Logo, gostaria que a saída se mantesse:

```
Nome = Lucas
Idade = 12
País = Brasil
```

Comment: O que acontece se você tirar o `--` do `--idade` no `add_argument`?

Comment: Aliás, por que para exibir o nome você coloca `args.arquivo`? Para idade você coloca `args.nome`?

Comment: Perdão amigo, erro de digitação, na questão do nome "arquivo"

Comment: Em relação aos ```-``` e ```--``` é só um padrão que quero adotar, mas não seria necessário

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta informar que "idade" é um argumento posicional, retirando os hífens e deixando apenas o nome:

```
parser.add_argument('idade', type=int) # retire o "--"
```

Também incluí o `type`, indicando que ele deve ser um número inteiro (assim ele já validará, retornando um erro caso não seja fornecido um número).

Assim, você pode chamar de qualquer um dos 3 jeitos abaixo:

```
python arquivo.py 12 -nome Lucas --pais Brasil
python arquivo.py -nome Lucas 12 --pais Brasil
python arquivo.py -nome Lucas --pais Brasil 12
```

No caso, "idade" será o primeiro argumento que não esteja no formato `--nome valor`, por isso as três opções acima funcionam. E também não precisa de `required`, pois por padrão ele já será obrigatório.

Para mais detalhes, veja a [documentação de `add_argument`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument).

Answer (score 5):

Como a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#name-or-flags) cita, o fato de você remover os hifens do nome do argumento faz com que ele seja um argumento posicional do seu comando e, assim, não precisa informar o nome (leia mais sobre POSIX para entender o padrão).

Então ao invés de:

```
parser.add_argument('--idade', required=True)
```

Faça:

```
parser.add_argument('idade', type=int)
```

Assim, você pode executar o comando `-nome Lucas 12 --pais Brasil` com sucesso.